# How can I wrap text so it appears in a single column with flying-saucer?

Tags: pdf, flying-saucer

I have a document specification for an invoice and one of the elements displays text vertically.  So like this:

```
H   123 Elm St
O   PO Box 1
M   Anytown, ST
E   USA
```

I have tried using both the css transform to rotate the text so it reads sideways.  I also tried using a table with a column width of 1 and then the address in a different column.  In a browser it renders correctly.  When I run it through the ITextRenderer, it doesn't wrap the characters(I am using spaces between each character so it should wrap).  I tried this after the transform and rotate produced the same result.

I also tried the table-layout:fixed; css setting, with no luck.  I end up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The css `transform` property is not supported by Flyingsaucer.

But the option to put the text in a narrow column should work.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td{border:1px solid blue}   
        .first{width:5mm;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">H O M E</td>
            <td>
                123 Elm StO<br />
                PO Box 1<br />
                Anytown, ST<br />
                USA
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It produces the following result:
[image: PDF result]

I used flying saucer 9.1, and the java code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        String in = "so1.html";
        String out = "so1.pdf";

        File f = new File(in);
        String url = f.toURI().toURL().toString();

        createPDF(url, out);
    }

    public static void createPDF(String url, String pdf) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdf)) {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(url);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything special you have to do in the java code or are you basically sucking this in as a string and outputting to pdf?  I didn't use mm in my css, I think I just used a number(I ended up having to put it on top instead of on the side).

Comment: There is nothing specific in the java code (see my updated answer). Regarding the column with, I used `mm`, but you can use any other unit (`px`, `pt`, ...), just make sure the col is large enough.